Understanding Peak in Spectrum Poking Through Noise Floor
Let's say I have FT spectral magnitudes with peaks from a signal showing through a curved noise floor coming from other (non-signal) noise sources. Let's say we have a peak whose top is at -35dB. Does that mean that the amount of true signal is -35dB, or that the true signal is the difference between -35dB and whatever the noise floor is around that frequency (in this case, the noise floor looks to be around -45dB, so then that option would mean the true signal is 10dB)?
Second, how would the answer change if the y axis was in linear amplitude? What about in power?
EDIT: Asked a different way — let’s say there were two identical rooms with a microphone and we can turn on a sound generator going at a single frequency. There is also random noise coming from some noise generator. The only difference between rooms is that the noise generator is turned up more in one. In each case, we get some curved noise floor until we turn on the signal generator and a spur/peak appears. Question: would the top of the peak have the same y value (in dB? linear amplitude? power?) in both rooms?


There is no way to distinguish signal from noise in this case unless it is specified what the signal is expected to be. The "Signal" or the "Noise" could be consisting of everything shown or just one or many of those "spurs" which is what single specular components are often referred to as when they are part of the noise. So without that I will refer to the plot as representing the frequency domain of a "waveform", where that waveform can contain "signal" and "noise" components.
If the "signal" was expected to be single tone at 100 Hz, then yes it's level would be -35 dB below the 0 dB reference. For the noise relative to the signal we would need to know exactly how the spectrum was created since that measurement would have an associated "resolution bandwidth" such that the noise given for each sample shown in frequency is the noise power within a certain bandwidth. If we were interested in the SNR within that bandwidth specifically, then yes the SNR would be approximately 10 dB.  If our measurement system where this is to be used had a much wider bandwidth, then the SNR would be significantly smaller (as the total noise would be the integration of the noise shown over that bandwidth).
To accurately represent the 100 Hz signal between the time domain and frequency domain, use the scaled FFT as given below:
$$X(f) = \frac{1}{W}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(x[n])(w[n])e^{-j2\pi n k/N}$$
Where $W$ is the sum of the window coefficients: $W=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}w[n]$
And the rest of the equation after $\frac{1}{W}$ is what the FFT returns, (So basically scale the FFT result by the sum of the window used, so if no further windowing is used, then divide by $N$ as in the total number of samples in the FFT. I also recommend zero padding the waveform out to 4 to 10x the length (after multiplying with the window) to eliminate the effect of scalloping loss.  This will result in the tones given in the FFT result being very accurate to the levels as given by the coefficients of the exponential frequencies in the positive and negative frequency diretions. Specifically for example the coefficients for a cosine wave are 0.5 as given by Euler's formula:
$$\cos(\omega t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{j\omega t} + \frac{1}{2}e^{-j\omega t}$$
So if the waveform is real and you only want to plot the positive axis, and have the magnitudes represent instead the coefficients of cosines, then you would simply double the result I provided earlier.
As far as the last question, we can convert from dB to linear magnitude quantity using:
$$A = 10^{dB/20}$$
And to a power quantity using
$$P = 10^{dB/10}$$
Additional comments about the OP's first plot (plot was later updated to only show a single spur, the first plot had multiple spurs):
The low frequency extent of what is shown is essentially "high-pass filtered" by the observation time duration of the signal (to truly observe "DC" would require an infinite observation time). Since the observation time is not given, we are not sure from the plot how much of the low frequency component of the waveform is actually presented.
The plot itself appears to be similar to what I would commonly see as phase noise on an oscillator phase locked to a reference oscillator (PLL), where "0" on the horizontal axis would be the center frequency of the oscillator and the frequencies as shown would be the power spectral density due to phase fluctuations in that single tone as produced by the oscillator. Seeing such spurs would also be common for such implementations, and in that case would clearly be part of the "noise" as well as the entire spectrum shown. If this is the case, then 0 dB would be the reference level of the oscillator output and the vertical axis would be given as "dBc" meaning dB below the carrier. Also if the resulting spectral was an actual spectral density then the vertical axis would be "dBc/Hz".  From the results shown (if this was even a phase noise plot) I suspect this is an FFT Spectrum and not a spectral density (so converted to a spectral density by subtracting $10Log_{10}(f_s)$ where $f_s$ is the sampling rate.

Thanks! I’ll need a couple rereads to let this sink in, but first let me ask my question in a different way: let’s say there were two identical rooms with a microphone and we can turn on a sound generator going at a single frequency. There is also random noise coming from some noise generator. The only difference between rooms is that the noise generator is turned up more in one. In each case, we get some curved noise floor until we turn on the signal generator and a spur/peak appears. Question: would the top of the peak have the same y value (in dB? linear amplitude? power?) in both rooms?

@empty-inch Assuming if there was no noise you got the same peak (meaning everything else is the same) then the peak when noise is added goes up by $10\log_{10}(1+10^{-dB/10})$ where "dB" is how much lower in dB the noise is in the immediate vicinity of the peak (assuming you windowed the FFT to have low sidelobe leakage). For example in your plot the noise (within the vicinity of the peak) is 10 dB lower, this would then come out to raising the measured peak about 0.4 dB (it's just a power sum of signal and noise).  Hope this helped!

Thanks! I thought I had it, but I got something slightly different: If noise + signal is -35dB, and there is -45dB of noise when there's no signal, then converting to linear power, subtracting, and going back to dB gives that the pure signal (no noise) is $10log(10^{-35/10} - 10^{-45/10})$.  So the amount the peak goes up (in dB plot) when noise is added vs no noise is (signal+noise in dB) - (signal in dB) = $$10log(10^{-35/10}) - 10log(10^{-35/10} - 10^{-45/10})=-10log((10^{-35/10} - 10^{-45/10})/10^{-35/10}) = -10 log(1-10^{-dB/10})$$ with 'dB' defined like yours.  Did I go wrong somewhere?

@empty-inch looks like you have it right. You started with noise and signal and thus it would drop by .4 dB if you took away noise. I started with signal and added noise and thus it goes up by 0.4 dB in my case

Thanks! Our answers are slightly different though (they just both round to about 0.4) so is the difference that you assumed that we have -35dB of pure signal and -45dB of pure noise, whereas I assumed that we have -35dB of signal + noise (which is equivalent to saying a spectrum of signal + noise would have a peak with a height of -35dB, right? That was my original question so just want to double check) and -45dB of noise?

Clarifying the parenthetical question in my last comment: that is, when both signal and noise are present if the y value at the relevant bin will read -35dB that means we have -35dB of signal + noise right? (NOT -35dB of signal?)

Yes agree ………….
